# Can not use the static methods from base class(Objective C) in my derived class(Swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, static-methods

I have a Swift project. I use FMDBx framework there and connect it via bridging-header because it is Objective C. I have my class    Job.swift which inherits FMXModel class from FMDBx framework:

```
class Job: FMXModel {
    dynamic var Id:NSNumber?
    dynamic var Sync: NSNumber?
    dynamic var Name: NSString?
    //...
}
```

The FMXModel class has few static methods:

```
  + (FMXModel *)modelByPrimaryKey:(id)primaryKeyValue;

  + (FMXModel *)modelByPrimaryKey:(id)primaryKeyValue database:(FMDatabase *)db;
```

My problem is that I can not use these methods from Job class. I only can type something like

```
 var model = FMXModel(byPrimaryKey:74)
```

Which is absolutely meaningless for me.
But I want something like:

```
 var job = Job(byPrimaryKey:74)
 //or may be
 var job = Job.modelByPrimaryKey(74)
```

Please, help me how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are the static methods defined in the .h file?

Comment: Are you directly adding the FMDBx framework to your project. i.e. are you dragging the .xcodeproj of FMDBx to your project ?

Comment: I used to be a great FMDB fan. It was the way to go when doing projects in Objective-C. However if you're not tied to it consider SQLite.swift. It's clean, fast and ... in swift. Never had any troubles with it.

Comment: I add it via cocoapods and then copy all folder with my framework to my project. And all the static methods are defined in .h files

Comment: @Marina why you want to use method with Job? b'coz you can directly use that method with the class name and you have tried this also in second coding portion.

Comment: @Marina i think you want to create your custom class to convert FMXModel to Job class right?

Comment: @JAY RAPARKA Yes, you are absolutely right. I want to get the instance of Job class with this method.

Comment: @Marina i had create one simple demo project and it will not give any error and works perfect so how can i send you

Comment: @JAY RAPARKA Very nice of yours. My e-mail is marinazayceva89@gmail.com.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90512/discussion-between-jay-raparka-and-marina).